# Ubuntu 13.10 fail to load graphics driver, black screen after login

Tags: 13.10, xorg, fglrx

I accidentaly chose the properitary driver in additional drivers in my machine instead of the xorg, and suddenly i cannot login, i uninstall fglrx deleted xorg.conf but i can't still login.w hat do i do?

Answer (score 0):

most people uninstall by only `apt-get remove` but the better way is to use `apt-get purge`

So try to purge fglrx

Also DebOrphan deltes anything left over and unneeded packages.

Comment: I did that already, passing --purge after remove

Comment: DebOrphan might help you.

Comment: I already did that but, i still lack my task bar, and title bars od applications... Unity semEms not working

Comment: if you can access terminal by Ctrl+Alt+T then run this script as root `apt-get update -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get check -y && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get autoclean -y`